# How to create knob for navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, slidingdrawer

I want create knob for my navigation drawer like below image
but I don't know what can I search in google

[image]

Comment: [Sliding Drawer](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/765) will help in your case.

Comment: maybe that's using html css code. not xml

Comment: like customized the sliding Drawer.....

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira: It's definitely not CSS. The screenshot is from an Android app.